# Heroku Ruby (Jekyll) & Go build packs

Tags: ruby, go, heroku, jekyll

I'm trying to build a web app with Jekyll and Go, where I use Go to embed the generated `_site` file from the Jekyll build & add some HTTP handlers with the conditions I need.

```
remote: -----> Using buildpacks:
remote:        1. heroku/ruby
remote:        2. heroku/go
```

My `Procfile`:

```
release: bundle exec jekyll b
web: ./bin/my-app
```

At the start of the buildpack, it's just fine. But when running buildpack in Go (specific on `Determining packages to install` step), it tries to compile, NOT to install required packages (like `go mod download`).

This really doesn't make sense actually. Because during Go buildpack, I embed `_site` with `go:embed` which directory should be generated after `release` phase.

Any chance to get rid of this?